# Docker daemon not running in Docker toolbox

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I created a sample microservice application with war file. After that I installed Docker tool box. Then I created sample Dockerfile and trying to build image using Docker toolbox quick start terminal.

I changed directory to project root directory, and ran the following command:

```
docker build -t "dockerDemo" .
```

And getting error like Docker daemon is not running.

And also I run the following commands:

```
docker run hello-world
docker-machine ls
```

I am getting following results screens.

[image]

I am now just started with containers and Docker concept. How can I solve this?

Comment: Is docker setup complete? Try the following command **docker run hello-world**

Comment: yes. Run the command the same error getting. I updated in question.Can you please check?

Comment: looks like an UAC error. Run the docker-daemon as administrator and try again

Comment: could you share the output of `docker-machine ls` command?

Comment: yes. Updated screenshot. Can you check please?

Comment: unfortunately the only solution is to remove the vm and recreate it
`$ docker-machine rm default
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default`

Comment: Did you saw my updated result of both command as screen shot?

Comment: @PrinceVargheseV is there a proxy?

Comment: Actually I have a remote server . I installed docker toolbox on that. The updated screenshot is my local machine. Now I am trying on my local windows 10 Home machine and getting result like above image.Can you check ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164325/discussion-between-andolsi-zied-and-prince-varghese-v).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to your screenshots, it's a pretty common issue. Unfortunately the only solution is to remove the vm and recreate it. You can find more details in this [issue](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/317).

```
$ docker-machine rm default
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete de Docker toolbox virtualbox vm. It is usually named "default". Close and open again the docker console, it will create again the vm automatically. Then try again.

Comment: That's true. Just suggesting an option to see if is valid for the OP.